# Rails validate has_many association against other objects in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

Say I have a `PhoneNumber` polymorphic model.  Many different models can `have_many` phone_numbers.  The forms on the frontend may differ slightly from model to model, but say I have a User form that allows phone numbers like this:

User:

`first phone: ___________`

`second phone: __________`

`third phone: ___________`

---

The User model `has_many` phone_numbers and `accepts_nested_attributes` for them as well.  Say I have a requirement that phones must be filled out in order.

I assume that means submitting all fields as empty strings and allowing server to do validations.  But how will it know if one `PhoneNumber` is alone or not?

---

For example,  if I submit this form:

User:

```
first phone: ___________

second phone: 123-456-7890

third phone: 123-456-7890
```

There should be an error that looks something like this:

`second phone: 123-456-7890 "error: cannot add phone number when 1st number is blank"`

---

Or if I had a more complex form is submitted:

User:

```
first phone: ___________

second phone: 123-456-7890 "error: cannot add phone number when 1st number is blank"

third phone: 123-456-7890

fourth phone: ___________

fifth phone: 123-456-7890 "error: cannot add phone number when 4th number is blank"

sixth phone: 123-456-7890
```

---

What is most elegent way of handling this?  Sending empty strings to the server and parsing them out seems dirty to me.  Here is code I have so far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phone_numbers, as: :callable
  validate :phones_cant_be_incorrect_order

  private

  def phones_cant_be_incorrect_order
    return unless phone_numbers.size > 1
    intentional_phone_numbers.each.with_index do |_phone, i|
      previous_number = i.ordinalize
      errors.add(
        :"phone_numbers.number",
        "can't add phone number when #{previous_number} number is blank"
      ) unless previous_number_present?(phone_numbers, i)
    end
  end

  # Parse out empty strings
  # Example: If only first_phone was filled out, delete all other empty strings.
  def intentional_phone_numbers
    last_number_present = phone_numbers.reverse.find { |x| x.number.present? }
    right_index = phone_numbers.index(last_number_present)

    bad = phone_numbers[(right_index + 1)..-1]
    self.phone_numbers = phone_numbers - bad
  end

  def previous_number_present?(array, index)
    return true if index.zero?
    array[index - 1].number.present?
  end
end
```

---

That's a LOT of code just to make sure that nothing gets submitted out of order.  Surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 0):

What is the importance of the order of phone numbers?
If you just want to omit fields that are empty strings try https://github.com/rubiety/nilify_blanks

I'm not sure why your validating the phone numbers in the User model in the first place.  Why not validate them in the model they belong to?